# When trying to convert a string in form "−0.06" to a numeric get NA

Tags: r

```
x <-  "−0.06"
x %>% as.numeric()
[1] NA
```

According to [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/negative-number-is-character-want-to-change-to-double/27246/2) post, simply using as.numeric should automatically take care of negative number values within a string, but not in my case.

I'm using dplyr::mutate across a variable with some negative and positive values. If I cannot use as numeric, what can I do here to handle the negative cases if they are in the form of the above?

Comment: It works well for me!

Comment: Hmm! Must be my set up. Should I output sessionInfo()?

Comment: From the post you linked to: "My guess: _your dash is not the right dash_. Use `charToRaw` and see what comes out. It should look something like this:..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seems to be symbol `−` which is not `-`.  It can be a result of copying directly from pdf and got a different symbol.  If we create a new one

```
x <- "-0.06"
as.numeric(x)
#[1] -0.06
```

Using the OP's code

```
as.numeric(x)
#[1] NA
```

The difference can be spotted if we convert to `raw`

```
charToRaw(x) # from OP's post
#[1] e2 88 92 30 2e 30 36
```

with the symbol alone

```
charToRaw("−")
#[1] e2 88 92
```

The one constructed fresh

```
charToRaw(x)
#[1] 2d 30 2e 30 36
```

actual `-`

```
charToRaw("-")
#[1] 2d
```

Comment: Correct, copy pasted data from a wikipedia page!